# Suppose that Z10 and Z15 are both homomorphic images of a finite group G. What can be said about |G|?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The solution I am seeing says that |G| is divisible by 10 and 15, and that the lcm of these is 30, but I do not understand why I know |G| is divisible by these numbers (the order of Z10 and Z15), or why the lcm is significant. If any insight could be offered it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By the first isomorphism theorem and Lagrange's theorem, $10\big| |G|$ and $15\big||G|$ so we see that $\text{lcm}(10,15)\big||G|$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rho$ is a homomorphism from $G$ to some group $H$. Now we know there is some homomorphism such that $\rho(G) = C_{10}$. The (first) Isomorphism Theorem states that $G/Ker(\rho) = C_{10}$ so in particular $|G|/|Ker(\rho)| = 10$ or $|G| = 10 \cdot |Ker(\rho)|$. A similar argument shows that $15 \mid |G|$.

Thus $10, 15 \mid |G|$. Now if $a\mid c$ and $b\mid c$ then $lcm(a,b)\mid c$ so 30 divides $|G|$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall the First Isomorphism Theorem.  It tell us that if $f: G \to G'$ is a homomorphism, then $G/ker(f) \cong G'$.  Moreover, by Langrange's Theorem, $|ker(f)|$ divides $|G|$.  So by our hypothesis, there exists homomorphisms $f$ and $g$ such that $|G|/|ker(f)| = |Z_{10}| = 10$ and $|G|/|ker(g)| = |Z_{15}| = 15$. So $|G|/10 = |ker(f)|$ and $|G|/15 = |ker(g)|$  and so 10 and 15 divide |G|.